# Complement of Nagata points set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have one question, is the complement set P^2\S a path-connected topological subspace, where S is a set of Nagata points (point in general position)?
thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Please define all your notation.